# Assign polygon to data point in R dataframe

Tags: r, polygon, mgcv

I have a two data frames:

- `points` contains a series of points  with `x, y` coordinates.
- `poly` contains coordinates of two polygons (I have over 100 in reality, but keeping it simple here).

I want to be able to add to the dataframe `points` an extra column called `Area` which contains the name of the polygon the point is in.

```
poly <- data.frame(
pol= c("P1", "P1","P1","P1","P1","P2","P2","P2","P2", "P2"),
x=c(4360, 7273, 7759, 4440, 4360, 8720,11959, 11440,8200, 8720),
y=c(1009, 9900,28559,28430,1009,9870,9740,28500,28040,9870))

points <- data.frame(
       object = c("P1", "P1","P1","P2","P2","P2"),
       timestamp= c(1485670023468,1485670023970, 1485670024565, 1485670025756,1485670045062, 1485670047366),
       x=c(6000, 6000, 6050, 10000, 10300, 8000),
       y=c(10000, 20000,2000,5000,20000,2000))

plot(poly$x, poly$y, type = 'l')
text(points$x, points$y, labels=points$object )
```

So essentially in this example the first 2 rows should have `Area= "P1"` while the last point should be blank as the point is not contained in any polygon.

I have tried using the function `in.out` but haven't been able to build my data frame as I described.

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is using a `for` loop, it is practically quite fast.

```
library(mgcv)

x <- split(poly$x, poly$pol)
y <- split(poly$y, poly$pol)

todo <- 1:nrow(points)
Area <- rep.int("", nrow(points))
pol <- names(x)

# loop through polygons
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  # the vertices of i-th polygon
  bnd <- cbind(x[[i]], y[[i]])
  # points to allocate
  xy <- with(points, cbind(x[todo], y[todo]))
  inbnd <- in.out(bnd, xy)
  # allocation
  Area[todo[inbnd]] <- pol[i]
  # update 'todo'
  todo <- todo[!inbnd]
  }

points$Area <- Area
```

Two reasons for its efficiency:

- `for` loop is through the polygons, not points. So if you have 100 polygons and 100000 points to allocate, the loop only has 100 iterations not 100000. Inside each iteration, the vectorization power of C function `in.out` is exploited;
- It works in a progressive way. Once a point has been allocated, it will be excluded from allocation later. `todo` variable controls the points to allocate through the loop. As it goes, the working set is reducing.

Comment: That's perfect thank you very much. Also runs very quickly on my large sample.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `point.in.polygon` from package `sp`:

```
points$Area = apply(points, 1, function(p)ifelse(point.in.polygon(p[3], p[4], poly$x[which(poly$pol==p[1])], poly$y[which(poly$pol==p[1])]), p[1], NA))
```

gives you

```
  object   timestamp     x     y Area
1     P1 1.48567e+12  6000 10000   P1
2     P1 1.48567e+12  6000 20000   P1
3     P1 1.48567e+12  6050  2000 <NA>
4     P2 1.48567e+12 10000  5000 <NA>
5     P2 1.48567e+12 10300 20000   P2
6     P2 1.48567e+12  8000  2000 <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked well. Agreed that on the larger dataset the loop is a faster solution, but thanks for your help